# Login screen doesn't prompt for password

Tags: login, password

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10, and tied it to my company LDAP.  On the login screen, instead of prompting for a password there is just a "Log In" button by my name.  I click it, and I am immediately logged in without typing in a password.  I checking my User Account options, and "Automatic Login" is turned off.  I can also click on other LDAP users accounts, and get in without a password.

There is a local user on the system.  When I try to log in as that user, I am prompted for a password.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a bit like you don't have a password set for your account. To verify this, try the following:

1. Head back into the User Account settings
2. Choose 'Unlock' from the upper right (if my assumption is correct, you should not be asked for a password)
3. Click on the string of dots next to the 'Password' field
4. Choose a new password, making sure to leave the 'Current Password' field blank.

If you really didn't have a password set, then you should do now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I was in our LDAP group with GID 119, which on this system happens to be the nopasswdlogin group.  I fixed the problem by changing the GID to another number.
I believe group 119 was the admin group on Fedora when we setup our LDAP a while back.